# I am having issues connecting to phpmyadmin via mysql in php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm just trying to connect to the databases in my website's phpmyadmin via mysql and am not getting anywhere...

here is my connect in php:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("website.com","username", "password");
```

And my host gives me DirectAdmin to manage mysql access, (as well as everything else) and I am on a laptop connected to ftp editing the files of the website. I don't know what I'm suppose to do or what I'm doing wrong...

Everytime I try I refresh the mysql_connect, or any page that has it included, I get this:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'website.com' (111) in .../inc/mysqli_connect.php on line 3
```

Is there anything extra that I am suppose to do that I'm not doing?...

I am a beginner when it comes to connecting to mysql. I've been using xampp to practice phpmyadmin/mysql/php practice, and I just need to figure out what to do when connecting the phpmyadmin databases through mysql for the website...

Help?

Comment: Check if your MySql server allows connection from remote machines? Looks like you can only access from the same machine it is installed (good behavior). Try uploading the page to the server and check if you are able to connect.

Comment: if you are working on your local machine use 'localhost' instead as server like: `$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","username", "password");`

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me... I'm uploading a file, that has an upload code, to access the databases located on that server. (website.com) Does MySQL really need to allow remote privileges when it's on it's own server?

Comment: Check with the information provided by you hosting Co, or in the control panel, or their help system. There should be some indicator telling you what you should use as the Host parameter. They normally run one specific database server for many sites to share. So you should see something somewhere obvious indicating what you should use in the hosts param.

Comment: Yeah, it was that. The hosting admin panel is really interesting. It has specific names and users for every database, so I just had to create a new one, and voila! (DirectAdmin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("website.com","username", "password","your database name");
```

Comment: Thanks! I already figured that out though. (Last comment above) "Yeah, it was that. The hosting admin panel is really interesting. It has specific names and users for every database, so I just had to create a new one, and voila! (DirectAdmin)"